# Angularjs + Zurb Foundation, do they play well together?

Tags: angularjs, zurb-foundation

I'm having a hard time setting up a project with angular and foundation 3 (rails in backend). So I have been searching a lot but there aren't many results.

I'm serving angular from a subfolder (localhost:3000/app), and started the html something like this

```
!!!5
%html{ "ng-app" => "App" }
  %head
    -# I tried this for html5 url on angular, not so much help so far
      %base{:href => "/app/"}
    %title
      NG APP
      ...
  %body
    %header
      ...
    %main
      = yield
    %footer
      ...
    = javascript_include_tag "application"
    = yield :javascripts
```

A couple of view work just fine. But when I tried to use the foundations tab, I could make work, because angular pass the anchor as a url that shold be check against $routeProvider.

So, I check some question here, and part of the answers give me the impression that foundation work fine enabling html5 mode in angular. (Which I could make it) and other answers say that in order to make work foundation with angular should write a directive  for every component on foundation. Or the last case is moving to Twitter Bootstrap.

So, I can find a unified answer, could you please, confirm if right now I can use foundation with angular in a direct way. Thanks.

Comment: It depends on how exactly foundation works, it seems you should be able to potentially just bootstrap angular manually after foundation has finished making it's updates, assuming it doesn't further add/remove DOM elements and you don't expect to be able to bind to things on the foundation controls from within Angular.  Basically the problem is both of these libraries want to take control of the DOM most likely and to use $scope in Angular it needs to be aware of changes made in javascript (if this happens outside of an Angular component it won't $apply so watches don't update).

Comment: So far, the foundation grid works fine, but don't work well the componets of foundation

Answer (score 4):

The best choice would be wrapping Foundation plugins in angular services or using only CSS/SASS provided with the framework and recreating the behaviour from scratch. Focus on prototyping using markup + stylesheets and then create logic in the angular way. At least, this is what I would do if I needed / had to use Foundation.

Twitter Bootstrap works in a similar way and the only advantage of moving to this framework is the fact that you can find plenty of angular modules / directives wrapping available plugins. In this case you wouldn't have to do the same job twice and well.

1. Take a look here: http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/ in the first place.
2. Then look for bootstrap-based components in [Bower.io Components Directory](http://sindresorhus.com/bower-components/)

Also, as some people in the comments have mentioned, you might need to bootstrap you application manually, which is as simple as wrapping you app in a module and running:

```
angular.bootstrap(element[, modules]);

// http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.bootstrap
```

As I said, it's usually better not to reinvent the wheel.

**Edit:**

There's an interesting discussion on Google Groups regarding this topic (and unsurprisingly users' conclusions are quite similar): https://groups.google.com/d/msg/angular/Htkzt7Fsaog/TeFm5l4snTwJ

Comment: Well said, and this is going to be true for any framework. Angular by it's very nature handles DOM interaction and modification, so any framework component library is going to have problems.

Comment: Yeah, but the point is: even if you have to rewrite some stuff, usually it's cleaner and much takes less time when you do it the angular way.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an almost complete adaptation of the Angular UI Bootstrap components to the Foundation CSS: http://madmimi.github.io/angular-foundation/.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the angular-ui-foundation library on github, its probably the best place to start from,

https://github.com/mhayes/angular-ui-foundation